# Terraform: How to use locate the Bitnami Kafka AMI ID

Tags: apache-kafka, terraform, bitnami

I was wondering how to list all of the Bitnami Kafka AMI ID for all the size offering?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `aws_ami_ids` data source https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami_ids.html:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_ami_ids" "bitnami_kafka" {
  owners = ["979382823631"] # bitnami

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["bitnami-kafka-*"]
  }
}

output "bitnami_kafka_ids" {
  value = "${data.aws_ami_ids.bitnami_kafka.ids}"
}
```

This is more or less the same than doing:

`aws ec2 describe-images --owners 979382823631 --filters "Name=name,Values=bitnami-kafka-*"`, but with Terraform, it only returns the AMI ids.